# Passing parameters to forEach Iterator in nodejs async

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, async.js

I'm trying to pass parameters to the iterator function that the async node module requires.

```
async.forEach dbReply, mediaHandler(entry, event.folder, callback), (error) ->
   console.log error 

mediaHandler = (entry, folder, callback) ->
   console.log arguments
```

I constantly get ReferenceError: entry is not defined

Any clue on how can I pass the event.folder parameter to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want your `mediaHandler` function to return an iterator function:

```
mediaHandler = (folder, callback) ->
    (entry) ->
        # Do things with folder, callback, and entry.
        # folder and callback are available through the closure,
        # entry is supplied by forEach.
```

and then:

```
async.forEach dbReply, mediaHandler(event.folder, callback), (error) -> ...
```

Your `entry` argument is supplied by `forEach` when it calls the iterator but the other two arguments are (presumably) available when you're calling `async.forEach` so you're trying to curry a three argument `mediaHandler` to get a one argument function that `forEach` can deal with; there are other ways to do that in (Coffee|Java)Script but doing it by hand with a closure is probably the simplest.

Comment: They are both undefined when logging them

Comment: Where are you expecting them to come from? Who defines them?

Comment: entry should be the the value in the index the forEach is passing.
folder is provided by event.folder.
If I do: 
mediaHandler = (folder, callback) ->
   console.log folder
    (entry) ->

Folder is not undefined.

Comment: And what is `event.folder` in the caller? What are `folder` and `callback` when `mediaHandler` is called?

Comment: Maybe you should provide a functional example of your problem, there seems to be some important things that are missing.